# Leaflet: set initial center and zoom

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet and trying to work out how set the initial image center and zoom but can't seem to get this to work. I found these notes in the documentation: https://docs.eegeo.com/eegeo.js/v0.1.728/docs/leaflet/L.Map/

```
map = L.map('map', {
  center: [-203.8, 123.2],
  zoom: 10,
  crs: L.CRS.Simple
});
```

I'd like the initial zoom and center to be the lowest point marked on this image: https://jsfiddle.net/brutaldigital/yx3ofrL4/2/

Thanks in advance for any suggestions, and apologies for the basic question (#newbie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your markers in an array:

```js
var markers = [];

markers.push(
  L.marker([-164, 121])
    .bindLabel('Monro's studio, 1 Henrietta Street, Covent Garden', { noHide: true })
    .addTo(map)
);

markers.push(
  L.marker([-160, 178])
    .bindLabel('The Royal Academy', { noHide: true })
    .addTo(map)
);

markers.push(
  L.marker([-200, 66])
    .bindLabel('St Martin&#39;s Workhouse', { noHide: true })
    .addTo(map)
);
```

Find the lowest marker:

```js
var lowestMarker = null;

markers.forEach(function(marker) {
  if (!lowestMarker) {
    lowestMarker = marker;
  } else if (marker.getLatLng().lat < lowestMarker.getLatLng().lat) {
    lowestMarker = marker;
  }
});
```

Pan the map to the lowest marker coordinates:

```js
map.panTo(lowestMarker.getLatLng());
```